# How to iteratively, manually label unicode text in python

Tags: python, ocr, handwriting

I want to label unicode handwriting characters in python/opencv. I have a segmented text image which I want to label iteratively by looking at images visually and labeling them manually to use these as training set.

Can you tell me how I can match a handwritten character with unicode character in python? For instance, a list of handwritten characters with matching unicode label.

Comment: I would follow a standard unicode table and label your training set accordingly. The table provides the mapping, which you could automate in Python. There may also be labelled training sets out there for this problem, but probably not for your specific handwritten images.

Comment: @Chuck Ivan I figure a python list of segmented characters and a matching label from input () might work? I don't have access to training dataset.What do you mean when you say follow a standard unicode table, how?

Comment: I mean once you make a prediction on the handwritten image, you can translate that prediction from, say, a character in the English alphabet to a corresponding unicode character using a unicode character set. Check this out (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html). Hope that helps